# Matplotlib error bar not placed correctly

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, errorbar

I have the following variables:

```
     m = array(['2016-02-03T06:35:00.000000000', '2016-03- 07T12:09:00.000000000',
   '2016-04-05T07:57:00.000000000', '2016-05-03T10:29:00.000000000',
   '2016-05-30T19:23:00.000000000', '2016-08-11T05:03:00.000000000',
   '2016-09-06T04:27:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

   n = array([9.60257044e+05, 2.73061146e+05, 6.30219177e+04, 2.18310433e+07,
   1.25728987e+04, 1.21189090e+05, 1.20494747e+06])
   o = array([1.10110070e+06, 3.19370657e+05, 4.99755918e+04, 3.26636779e+07,
   1.89902834e+04, 1.16384062e+05, 1.07328724e+06])
```

while trying to plot error bar in matplotlib using the following code:

```
    plt.scatter (m, n)
    plt.errorbar (m, n, yerr = o)
```

the errorbar is plotted in the horizontal axis not on the vertical axis. What may be the possible reasons behind this and how to overcome this?
The plot is shown below[image]

Comment: only your 4th value in your o array is big enough to show up.  Try o=.5e7*ones(7) to see what your y error bars should look like. I don't get what you say about it being plotted on the horizontal axis

Comment: Thanks. It seems perfect with the revised scaling of y -axis. But why are there horizontal lines connecting the points? Should it not be only vertical line representing error? How can I get rid of those horizontal line connecting the points?